# Columns reversed because of ORDER BY statement

Tags: oracle

I am working on a report with the following code:

```
SELECT SUBS_PROV "PROV", SUM(PAID_AMT), 0, 0, 0, SUM(PAID_AMT)
FROM H 
WHERE GRP = :P_POLICY AND 
&P_DATE BETWEEN :P_FROM_DATE AND :P_TO_DATE 
GROUP BY SUBS_PROV
UNION ALL

SELECT PROV "PROV", 0, SUM(PAID_AMT), 0, 0, SUM(PAID_AMT)
FROM D
WHERE GRP = :P_POLICY AND 
&P_DATE BETWEEN :P_FROM_DATE AND :P_TO_DATE 
GROUP BY PROV
UNION ALL

SELECT PROV "PROV", 0, 0, SUM(PAID_AMT), 0, SUM(PAID_AMT)
FROM E
WHERE GRP = :P_POLICY AND 
&P_DATE BETWEEN :P_FROM_DATE AND :P_TO_DATE 
GROUP BY PROV
UNION ALL

SELECT SUBS_PROV "PROV", 0, 0, 0, SUM(PAID_AMT), SUM(PAID_AMT)
FROM R 
WHERE GRP = :P_POLICY AND 
&P_DATE BETWEEN :P_FROM_DATE AND :P_TO_DATE 
GROUP BY SUBS_PROV
```

There is a TOTAL column in this query in the Data Model, and I have to add "ORDER BY" because under Oracle 11g group by no longer works.

When I add "ORDER BY 1" at the very end, and run the report, it reverses the totals of H with the totals of the TOTAL column. Is there a way to add ORDER BY without reversing these columns?

Thanks!

Comment: "under Oracle 11g group by no longer works" - err?

Comment: I can confirm after empirical testing that GROUP BY does indeed work in 11g. Therefore it must your use of it that isn't working in 11g.

Comment: @Ollie - I suspect the issue is that GROUP BY uses a more efficient hashing algorithm in 11g (and has done since 10g) which means results are no longer sorted by the aggregating columns.  Whereas  in earlier versions of Oracle GROUP BY did return the results sorted.  The docs listed this as a design side-effect which could not be relied upon: only ORDER BY guarantees sort order.  However, in practice GROUP BY did the trick so many people *did* rely on it and didn't bother with the extra sort.  Hence the shock when "under Oracle 11g group by no longer works".

Comment: APC, i know, i was just making a point.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `ORDER BY` after each `GROUP BY` instead of only at the end.